# Content over 64kb not showing up in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am having a bit of an issue with a particular page on my wordpress site. Because of the design, the page is quite large in size as it has multiple internal tabs etc etc. The trouble is that all of a sudden I stopped being able to add content. Litterally as soon as you saved the page it just cuts off the content.

The problem is not content related as I have tried it with just plain ol' text and the same thing happens. I have searched like mad for similar issues to no avail.

So far I have re-installed wordpress, checked all plugins, checked that it isn't a theme based issue. Interestingly under a wordpress.com hosted blog, I am able to add over the 64kb limit no problem so I immediately went to my hosting provide. They have been absolutely useless and simply said that there are no errors showing up server side.

Through research I have heard people talking about BLOBS and MEDIUMBLOBS but im not really too sure how to manipulate MySQL settings.

Anyone that could point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post the db schema - that is where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help folks.

I managed to track it back to the suhosin php script. I was advised to check into the suhosin.post.max_value_length. variable. When I upped the value to 3 x the 64k it was set to, it made no difference. That said, I asked my host to just turn the script off and I am back in business!

Answer (score 0):

In table wp_posts (in MySQL - checking with PhpyMyAdmin is easiest) check the field types  of "post_content" and "post_content_filtered". They should both the "longtext" which allows 4GB of post.

If they are not "longtext" then simply change the type to "longtext" and you should be right. (also check you have the latest version of WordPress - it was increased a long time ago, and you may have a very outdated verions!)

If they are "longtext" then you must have a plugin that probably stores it's own version of the data in another table, or a plugin that truncates the strong along the way. Just disable the plugins one by one until the problem goes away - then check with the developer of the plugin.

Comment: Asker said he's reinstalled WordPress, which may mean he's imported to a new DB. nice answer, though, and you may still be right.

Comment: Re-installed from scratch, including a clean DB, or reinstalled using existing DB? If re-installed with existing DB, and an upgrade missed adjusting the DB structure (although that was version 2.x?) then re-installing _may_ not fix the problem. But it's still the process to iron out the problem.

Comment: Oh, I know. That's why I said it's a nice answer: it's insightful. :)